# How to create Service Builder's tables in database?

Tags: mysql, service, builder

I have deleted a table of my service from (MySQL) database. And now have portlet error messages that table is not exist. How to initiate recreation? I had never created service tables manually. They were created automatically but now stopped.

*** UPDATE ***

By above I mean my custom tables of my custom portlet project. I have SQL files for them and off course can run them against a server, but wish to know how it should be done normally?

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have the installation files?  If so, search them for the tablename.  On linux this would be something like

```
find /path/to/top/directory -type f -print0 | xargs -0r grep -il 'CREATE TABLE Xyz'
```

where `Xyz` is the tablename you're looking for.  For each file it lists, search for `CREATE TABLE Xyz` and `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Xyz`.  That should find the 'create' statement for the missing table.  If the table also had triggers against it that will take further work.

If you don't have the installation files but you do have all of your binlogs, you can search (again in linux) those with

```
find /path/to/binlogs -type f -print0 \
| \
xargs -0r file \
| \
fgrep 'MySQL replication log' \
| \
cut -d: -f1 \
>/tmp/binlog.lst
for b in $(</tmp/binlog.lst); do
    echo -n $b
    mysqlbinlog $b | grep -li 'CREATE TABLE Xyz'
    echo
done
```

But even if either of those approaches works, it only gets you the original 'create' statement.  If the table had an 'alter table' in the installation or an upgrade then that's extra searching.

Without a backup I'd reckon you're best bet is to reinstall the same version of Service Builder and then copy the resulting table across to your current installation.

Before you go any further, take a backup of what you currently have, eg via something like `mysqldump --opt --all-databases >large_dump_file`

Comment: Sorry I was meaning custom tables of my custom portlet. Of course I have SQL files for them, but I wonder how the tables should be created normally?